# Display Strings from SharedPreferences in a table

Tags: android, android-listview, sharedpreferences

I come from iOS, and I am struggling to get my head about the SharedPreferences in Android.

I have a number of strings loaded into SharedPreferences, and I want to display them all in a ListView.

At the moment, I can only get them to display in LogCat.

Heres the code I have so far:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences",
        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Map<String, ?> prefsMap = preferences.getAll();
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry: prefsMap.entrySet()) {
        Log.v("SharedPreferences", entry.getValue().toString());

}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Where is your list view code ?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the input. I've got my list view working, and had a read about array adapters. I've come up against another issue with this list though, can anyone help out?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048436/how-to-delete-list-view-items-when-list-is-populated-by-sharedpreferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the following things to achieve this.

1. ListView in you layout.xml file (This will display your list)
2. instead of log store it in string arrayList
3. create ArrayAdapter for your listView with the String ArrayList.

for example follow this:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView lv;

    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list_view_id);

        SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ArrayList<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Map<String, ?> prefsMap = preferences.getAll();
        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : prefsMap.entrySet()) {
            your_array_list.add(entry.getValue().toString());
        }
        // This is the array adapter, it takes the context of the activity as a
        // first parameter, the type of list view as a second parameter and your
        // array as a third parameter.
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, your_array_list);

        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you were spot on. I'm now trying to delete items from the list, and I've got stumped by the array adapter again. While I go do some reading on the subject would you mind having a look at question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048436/how-to-delete-list-view-items-when-list-is-populated-by-sharedpreferences . Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct,

Please update your log displaying code line to

```
Log.v("SharedPreferences", entry.getValue().toString()+"--Value");
```

Because when entry.getValue().toString() returns null then logs will not displayed in logcat, There is a option that all your entries are null and thats why you are not seeing any log message in logcat.

NOTE:
If any entry (tag or msg) of [Log.v(TAG, MSG)] is null then log will not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `ArrayList<String>` and store your pref data, use `Adapter` and populate the `ListView`.

[This site](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) has detailed explanation on using it:

Answer (score 1):

For displaying it in a ListView you should look up how to use it, and how to use a ListAdapter.

Very good tutorial here and even shows best practices:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 1):

Try below code. This will helpful for you

```
enter code here


final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> LIST = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(pref, 0);
Map<String, ?> items = settings.getAll();
for(String s : items.keySet()){
HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
temp.put("key", s);
temp.put("value", items.get(s).toString());
LIST.add(temp);
```

}